# How can I change numberOfRowsInSection when I have multiple TableViews?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

This is my current code:

```
if (tableView == nearbyTV) {
    return numberOfObjects;
}
else {
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [searchResults count];
    } 
    else {
        return [users count];
    }
}
```

As you can see I am trying to reflect different indexes depending on the table view or a table view search display. The second view controller appears when the user clicks on a button. At this point if the second table view's index exceeds the first table view's index it crashes with the unfortunately familiar:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 13 beyond bounds [0 .. 12]'
```

What can I do to update the number of rows for the second table? Also I am some how getting information from the other table view as I am scrolling. Very frustrating. Any help at all would be very appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        if (tableView == friendsTV || tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";

        SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }else{
            cell.propic.image=nil;
            cell.flashBack.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
            [cell.button1 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            cell.fullName.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
        return cell;
        }else{
            static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"nearbyTableCell";

            nearbyTableCell *cell = (nearbyTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"nearbyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
            }else{
                cell.propic.image=nil;
                cell.flashBack.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
                [cell.button2 setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
            //    NSLog(@"%@",[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
            if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
                cell.fullName.text = [searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

            }else if (tableView==nearbyTV){
                NSString *requestCombine = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",[[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fbID"]];
                [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:requestCombine
                                             parameters:nil
                                             HTTPMethod:@"GET"
                                      completionHandler:^(
                                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                          id result,
                                                          NSError *error
                                                          ) {
                                          cell.fullName.text=[result objectForKey:@"name"];

                                      }];
                cell.fbIDLabel.text = [[json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"fbID"];
            }
            return cell;
        }

}
```

Comment: can you show cellForRow code?

Comment: You should use one tableviewController for one tableView.

Comment: post code of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: added `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  @SalmanZaidi @Akhilrajtr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not in using multiple `UITableView`s in one class.

From the error log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 13 beyond bounds [0 .. 12]'
```

It's clear that while creating cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, you are trying to access object at index 13 while the length of your array is 13 i.e., last index is 12. So try to debug your array and check mechanism of accessing objects from arrays while creating cells. May be you are returning an extra count in `numberOfRowsInSection` for your `nearbyTV` table.

**EDIT 1:** It's always a good option to set `Exception Breakpoint` in your projects as it tells you exact code-location of crash. Set Exception Breakpoint to trace the array on which crash occurred while accessing element to trace the real problem.

**EDIT 2:** As seen from your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`method, `searchResults` and `json` are the two arrays from which you are picking up objects to be displayed on cells. The row count returned from `numberOfRowsInSection` must match number of objects in `searchResults` and `json` arrays in order to make you code work properly. The problem lies in one of this array. Debug to see number of objects present in `searchResults` and `json` arrays and row count returned from `numberOfRowsInSection`method.

Comment: Thanks for your post, I added `cellForRowAtIndexPath` above. The arrays can change depending on how many friends are nearby and how many friends the user has.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i hope it may work for you ..

```
 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        if ([tableView isEqual:nearbyTV]) 
{
            return [Your nearbyTVarray's count];
        }
        elseIf ([tableView isEqual:nearbyTV])
    {
            return [searchResults count];
        }
       return [users count];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that which tableview is returning ,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
{
  if(tableView == firstTableView){ 
    return 10;
  }
  return 15;
}
```

It return first tableView 10 cells and other tableviews 15 cells.
modify the else condition with how many tableView you have.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
        if ([tableView isEqual:firstTableVIew]) 
        {
            return [array1 count];
        }
        elseIf ([tableView isEqual:secondTableView])
       {
            return [array2 count];
        }
    }
```

and make sure to add check of `if([tableView isEqual:yourTableVIew]` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` also

Answer (score -1):

Also assuming if each table view is assigned its own section:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section)
    {
        case 0: return [array1 count]; break;
        case 1: return [array2 count]; break;
        default: // Handle others
            break;
    }
}
```